# How to disable button when there are no records column using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, html

I want to disable the button if there are no records in a specific column in the database. I have two buttons in echo statement View and cancel. I am retrieving the value from the database and displaying. I want to disable button of that row which is no records. Would you help me in this?

```
<th>Name</th>  
 <th>Email</th>
 <th>Mobile</th>
  <th>action</th>



  <?php
    if (isset($all_records->num_rows) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $all_records->fetch_assoc()) {
         $name=$row['name'];
         $email=$row['email'];
        $mobile=$row['mobile']; 

        if ($email == 0 || $mobile==0) {
            //disable btn
            }
        else{
            //enable btn
        }   

        echo "
        <tr>
        <td>{$name}</td>
        <td>{$email}</td>
        <td>{$mobile}</td>
        <td class='in_set_btn'><a href='' class='btn'>view</a> <a href=''  class='btn'>Cancel</a></td>
        </tr>
  ";
   }
  }
```

Comment: Explain better  becasue  your code echo only existing rows  ..

Comment: Sure, I have 4 column in my table called as Id, Name, Email, Mobile and i am retrieve all records  and also displaying button. In case for row, Email and Mobile column is Null or empty then i want to disable the button

Comment: I assume `$email` and `$mobile` are string variables. So `if ($email == 0)` is wrong. What you have to do is: `if (empty($email) || empty($mobile)) {`

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.EhsanT, Thanks for information.I tried that but same issue

Comment: So, you want to check each record and it email or mobile was empty, then disable "view" and "cancel" links? If so how do you want to disable them? you want to show them but they do not have any links, or you do not want to show them or what?

Comment: @Hybreeder use ternary operator.Just one line code is enough for you.

Comment: Can you try now with modified code. It should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    if (isset($all_records->num_rows) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $all_records->fetch_assoc()) {
        $name=$row['name'];
        $email=$row['email'];
        $mobile=$row['mobile']; 
        $emailBtn = "<a href='' class='btn'>view</a>";
        $mobileBtn = "<a href='' class='btn'>cancel</a>";
        if (empty($email)) {
            $emailBtn = "<a disabled href='' class='btn'>view</a>";
        }
        if (empty($mobile)) {
            $mobileBtn = "<a disabled href='' class='btn'>cancel</a>";
        }

        echo "
            <tr>
            <td>{$name}</td>
            <td>{$email}</td>
            <td>{$mobile}</td>
            <td class='in_set_btn'>".$emailBtn.$mobileBtn."</td>
            </tr>
        ";
   }
?>
```

Comment: Thank for replying Mr.Yougesh, I tried your code. Not working

Comment: You want both the buttons to be hidden in case it is not valid??

Comment: Yes, or any one, Incase mobile and email fields are blank

Comment: Can you please clearly tell which button need to be shown and when. If mobile is not valid but email is valid, what should be the behavior or viceversa. Also, if both are valid, what should be there??

Comment: Mr. Yogesh Kumar, incase email is empty than view hide and mobile is empty tha cancel hide.

Comment: I have removed the button's code all together from document. In case you want to keep the button and hide them on the page, just give them a class of disabled and use css to display: none; or just add attribute disabled and you will no longer be able to click on the button

Comment: I tried your code it is working almost but little bit issue, button totally hide, I want to disable the button so user  can see it but not able to clicked

Comment: disabled  will not work with anchor tag. using css we can do.. Thanks for help Mr.Yogesh. it is working for me. Upvote from my side

Answer (score 0):

```
        <th>Name</th>  
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Mobile</th>
          <th>action</th>



          <?php
            if (isset($all_records->num_rows) > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $all_records->fetch_assoc()) {
                 $name=$row['name'];
                 $email=$row['email'];
                $mobile=$row['mobile']; 
        $disable = '';
                if ($email == 0 || $mobile==0) {
                    $disable = "disabled";
                    }
                else{
                    $disable = "";
                }   

                echo "
                <tr>
                <td>{$name}</td>
                <td>{$email}</td>
                <td>{$mobile}</td>
                <td class='in_set_btn'><a href='' {$disable} class='btn'>view</a> <a href='' {$disable} class='btn'>Cancel</a></td>
                </tr>
          ";
           }
          }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a ternary condition `(?:)` for define a variable `$disable`.Like this

```
$disable=  (empty($email)|| empty($mobile))?"disabled":" ";//if one of the column is empty return disabled
```

then add class in your button like this..

```
<td class='in_set_btn'><a href='' class='btn'".$disable.">view</a> <a href=''  class='btn'".$disable.">Cancel</a></td>
```

OR

```
<td class='in_set_btn'><a href='' class='btn' {$disable}>view</a> <a href=''  class='btn' {$disable}>Cancel</a></td>
```